# Is there always a unique path between nodes of different lengths?

Tags: graph-theory

Think of this like a variation traveling salesman problem. You have a bunch of cities which are all connected with roads of unique arbitrary lengths (i.e. uncorrelated to the distance between the cities). Forget about their intersections (pretend that at every intersection one tunnels beneath the other). Now, is there a unique route (you can choose where you start) that goes to every city once which travels the shortest distance (disregard the reverse path as not making the route unique) or can there be multiple routes with the same shortest distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the graph with $6$ vertices $u,v,w,x,y,z$ and $7$ edges with lengths $wx=1$, $xy=2$, $vx=3$, $wy=4$, $vw=5$, $uv=6$, $yz=7$. The two Hamiltonian paths are $uvwxyz$ and $uvxwyz$, both of length $21$.

If you wanted a complete graph, give the $8$ additional edges lengths $12$, $13$, $14$, $15$, $16$, $17$, $18$, $19$, so that none of them can be used in a Hamiltonian path of minimum length.

Answer (score 0):

There can certainly be multiple shortest paths.  A simple example is below.  The sides of the regular hexagon are all $1$.  The shortest path goes from $E$ to $C$ to $G$ to $C$ to $E$ where one $E$ to $C$ goes through $D$ and the other goes through $A$.  You can do the two $E$ to $C$s in either order as well as starting at $C$.  You can also start at other vertices.  We can play with the distances to make them all distinct without spoiling the situation if you prefer.[image]